# What does it mean to assign one or more function to a list in r?

Tags: r, list, function

For example in this example...
    list(set = set, get = get, setmean = setmean, getmean = getmean)

Comment: What would you guess?  It means you have a list of functions.  You can call a function using `yourList[["set"]](...)`

Comment: Please do some research of your own before asking an obvious question

Comment: In R, a function is an object. Because of this, functions like any other objects, can be assigned to a list. In fact, you can assign functions and other objects to the same list and R is just fine with it.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand it.

Comment: If for example I have the function:   set<-function(a) x<<-a  and the function    get<-function() x  . And then I do    list(set=set, get=get)    .How can I use the functions in this list???

Comment: See the first comment for how to use a function contained in a list. You might also use `lapply` to apply a number of functions to the same object and store the results in an orderly structure. This way, you could run this `lapply` over different objects and inspect the results using integer or name indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you want to ask but this is some information.

R is a functional languages, so you can manipulate functions like variables. This offers some benefits. For example, if you have a list of function, you can use lapply() to call all of them without typing manually and repeatedly some identical arguments.

```
summary <- function(x) {
funs <- c(mean, median, sd, mad, IQR)
lapply(funs, function(f) f(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

For more details, have a look at Hadley Wickham's [guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html).